# Magento 2 - Cart rule - Buy X get free gift

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

Is there any way or extension to set their cart rules?

> - Rule 1: buy X > 50 - get free gift A
> - Rule 2: buy Y > 100 - get free gift B

If order is made with Y > 100  AND X > 50

> - only get free gift B (not both)

And the other cart rules (if has) still kept

Comment: Magento 2 Shopping cart rules can not add other products to the cart.
It's a known limitation

Answer (score 0):

You can install third party extension to achieve your requirement.
There several extensions of **Free Gift** are available on internet.
You can find it out exactly per your need and install it in magento.
Enjoy vacation!